# Is there a way to use d:DesignData xaml at runtime?

Tags: xaml, prototype, windows-phone-7

I am building a prototype of a windows phone 7 app using d:DesignData in the SampleData folder. I would like the same design data to appear at runtime since this is just a prototype. Is there a way to set the DataContext to the same data xaml as the DesignData at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you included the sample data file in the project you could load it at runtime like any other XML file. You would need to deserialize or parse it yourself though.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for a baked in path

Comment: No, design data is intended for use at design/development time only so you can see how the app will look with "real data" in it without having to hardcode values.